# Sql error caused by wrong date format

Tags: c#, mysql, date

I'm having problems with the input datetime.now.toshortstring() where mysql uses the syntax for data yyyy-MM-dd and the propriety uses dd-mm-yyyy, and it's causing an error called "**An unhandled exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll
Additional information: Incorrect date value: '29-02-2016' for column 'DATA' at row 1**"

Here is the code:

```
            DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Deseja mesmo gravar estas alterações?", "Confirmação", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
               MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                string con = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=12345;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=portaria";
                string query = "Insert into entradas(id_veiculo,empresa_visitante,empresa_visitar,nome_condutor,visitado,ncartao,data,hora,obs) values('"+ msktxtmat.Text +"','"+ txtempvis.Text +"','"+ comboBox1.SelectedValue +"', '"+ txtnomecondutor.Text +"','"+ txtpessoavisitar.Text +"', '"+ txtncartao.Text +"', '"+ DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() +"', '"+ DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() +"','"+ txtobs.Text +"');";
                MySqlConnection Con = new MySqlConnection(con);
                MySqlCommand Command = new MySqlCommand(query, Con);
                MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.SelectCommand = Command;
                sda.Fill(dt);
            }
```

Yeah i know i should be using parameterized querys but actualy i dont wanna waste time rebuilding this code with parameterized, i'll just stick with the regular form here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use parameters, that will solve your formatting issues, also it will save you from SQL Injection.

Comment: `i know i should be using parameterized querys but actualy i dont wanna waste time`  so instead you are wasting your time wrestling with string dates, formatting issues, type conversions and that awful SQL string.

Comment: i know about it, but since this is a trash thing just to test this methods, i wont botter doing any parameters :p This is educational propose only, to show to my friends who are learning from ground the language, this will be more easy for them to understand this method. And i always use parameters on my projects, but not on those i wont publish, thanks in advance!

Comment: `to show to my friends who are learning from ground the language` then you are teaching them the wrong things

Comment: Well, your trash code taught you one thing already: Had you used parameterized queries in the first place, you'd have saved a lot of time you spent asking, discussing and reading here. So while you think it's a waste of time, it's actually a time-saver.

Comment: Downvoted for deliberately encouraging bad practices over robust, safe, canonical code. There is no excuse, and clearly no time saved here by not using parametrized queries.

Comment: You're teaching other people how to do this? You should teach them how to do SQL queries using an SQL tool (even the command line mysql tool will work). *Then*  teach them how to do it in code, but teach them how to do it right from the start. They *will* sooner or later publish stuff and they *will* use your so called "trash code" as the base of their work and we will continue having crap code with gate-wide security holes when it takes *one minute* to teach them the right thing...

Comment: its not about that, because i always tell them that this is a wrong system to follow, but they understand better with this kind of examples, just that bro, no worries :) And as i said before i use parameterized queries on my projects! not on this kind of examples, just that...

Comment: That's what I'm trying to tell you: To teach them SQL, you don't need C#. If you're at the point where C# comes in they will know enough SQL to understand parameterization. Do you have English songs that you sang with wrong words in your childhood? Do you still sing them wrong now you're grown up? Same thing here - wrong "knowledge" sticks around...

Comment: By "stick with the regular form", you mean continue following  the pattern that's been demonstrated time and time again to be vulnerable to SQL Injection. And you mean that developing code "using parameterized queries" would be a waste of time. Got it.

Comment: As i said, i always tell them to use parameters just like me, but since they can't understand much with it, i keep the things simplier to read, if they prefer this way, why should i complicate? I can't do nothing about it, they asked me to replicate something they wanted for their program, i just told them that this is not the best example, and by far, i'm not wrong if they prefer like this. It's just my opinion... Nothing else, i dont "encourage bad practices over robust, safe, canonical code" as @jeroenh says. I'm doing the things as they wish.

Comment: @spencer7593 i understand that for christ sake! I use parameterized queries myself! But what can i do if they want like this?! Should i stop helping them? OFC not!!!! I keep telling them that parameters work better, but that's not my decision! Its theirs, just understand that and stop mocking... I've told everyone that i dont use this method on my projects, this was an example! Got it?! Hope so...

Comment: Yes. Stop helping them. If they demand you teach them bad stuff, just don't.

Comment: Maybe you're right, but i don't care, i tell them that parameters work better  and bla bla bla, they keep doing like so, its their problem, i was just trying to solve a friend's problem, thats all... No need for that stupid kind of insults saying that you encourage bad practices when i try to teach them the right way, i think its not fair... But well, community its always like this, some of them help, others just like to mock people... Not your case.

Comment: I don't see how you're being insulted or mocked! Everybody is simply trying to encourage you to enforce the use of best practices. I don't see any insult here! It's just you becoming defensive.

Comment: Since i alredy said that i use the correct methods, why keep talking about it? Why even comment about this? I dont see much big of a deal here... Since i've learn'd everything i know on the internet, without any troubles. I just tryied to be nice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()
```

with

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

because mySQL requires a `yyyy-MM-dd` date format to recognize a string as a valid date

You mentioned that you don't want to use parameters - consider to use `MySqlHelper.EscapeString(TextBox.Text)` - that's another way to avoid injection attacks

Comment: as i said i wont be using parameters in this simple project, i'm just learing how to use datetime proprieties ;) I've tryied it with no success, what could lead to the problem? Error code: "**No overload for method 'ToShortDateString' takes 1 arguments**"

Comment: PS: Forget it!!! Yeah it works just fine, i was dumb enough not to copy and paste it ahahah, i was using the ToShortDateString instead of ToString ;) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Try to used parameterized queries! Why? Because without you are vulnerable to SQL Injections. Have a look [here](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/113/preventing-sql-injection-in-asp-net).
Do something like this:

```
    DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Deseja mesmo gravar estas alterações?", "Confirmação", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

    if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        string con = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=12345;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=portaria";
        string query = "Insert into entradas(id_veiculo,empresa_visitante,empresa_visitar,nome_condutor,visitado,ncartao,data,hora,obs) values(@msktxtmat, @txtempvis, @comboBox1, @txtnomecondutor, @txtpessoavisitar, @txtncartao, @dateTimeFirst, @dateTimeSeconds, @txtobs);";
        MySqlConnection Con = new MySqlConnection(con);
        MySqlCommand Command = new MySqlCommand(query, Con);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@msktxtmat", msktxtmat.Text);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtempvis", txtempvis.Text);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comboBox1", comboBox1.SelectedValue);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtnomecondutor", txtnomecondutor.Text);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtpessoavisitar", txtpessoavisitar.Text);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtncartao", txtncartao.Text);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateTimeFirst", DateTime.Now.Date);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateTimeSeconds", DateTime.Now.Date);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtobs", txtobs.Text);
        MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.SelectCommand = Command;
        sda.Fill(dt);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The value `29-02-2016` really is not a valid date time value from the database's view. You might want to use `2016-02-29` or even better, use parameterized queries.

> Yeah i know i should be using parameterized querys but actualy i dont wanna waste time rebuilding this code with parameterized, i'll just stick with the regular form here.

Using parameterized queries will *not only* protect you against SQL injections - it will also make sure that the data you pass in is converted to the correct format.

So using parameterized queries you do not only have less worries (for example: how do I format dates correctly?), but as an added bonus it makes your application more secure.

There's really no excuse for *not* using parameterized queries...

> the regular form

What is the regular form? I consider parameterized queries the regular form.

Comment: the regular form i was talking is the more logical thing, so newbies could understand what the commands are doing. Before i started parameterized, i used this kind of simple mysql commands to learn, thats my goal, to teach my friends this simple steps, but at the same time advice them to use parameters to avoid injections, just that! :)